# problema al editar campo emial ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy teniendo problemas en un edit de mi tabla Users. Me funciona el edit de todos los campos menos el del email. 
El codigo de mi controlador users es el siguiente:

```
def update
success = false
if @user.valid?
  if user_params[:password].present?
    success = @user.update(user_params)
  else
    success = @user.update_without_password(user_params)
  end
end

if success
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t("flash.users", message: I18n.t('admin.users.flash.updated'))
  redirect_to admin_users_path
else
  render :edit
end
end

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:cui,
                             :pin,
                             :email,
                             :name,
                             :password,
                             :password_confirmation,
                             :role,
                             :locked,
                             :managements_attributes => [:id, :doctor_id, :secretary_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Y mi view edit User es la siguiente:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user], :html => { :role => "form" } do |f| %>

<div class="form-group required col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= f.label :cui %>
  <%= f.text_field :cui, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control required" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group required col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control required" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= f.label t('admin.users.edit.email') %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= f.label :current_password %> 
  <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: "form-control"  %>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= f.label :pin %>
  <%= f.text_field :pin, class: "form-control", disabled: true %>
</div>

<% unless current_user.id == @user.id %>
<div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= f.label t('admin.users.edit.role') %>:
  <%= f.select :role, role_options(User) %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Las validaciones del modelo son las siguientes:

```
# == Validations
validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
validates_inclusion_of :role, in: ROLES
validates :pin, uniqueness: true
validates :name, :email, presence: true
validates :cui, numericality: true, unless: -> { role_admin? || role_secretary? }, presence: true  
validates :email, :cui, uniqueness: true
validates :cui, length: { is: 11 }, unless: -> { role_admin? }    
validate  :cui_must_exists_to_register, on: :create, if: -> { role_provider? }
```

Comment: ¿y que te muestra el log? ¿ves que vaya el campo de email en los parámetros efectivamente? ¿ves que esté siendo agregado en el `UPDATE` que registra el log? ¿hay alguna posibilidad de que el campo este siendo cambiado/borrado a nivel de js o de alguna validación del modelo? ¿quizás estés usando alguna gema de autenticación en el modelo que pueda estar bloqueando la edición de email?

Comment: Como puedo ver el log de esa parte? En realidad no me edita todo menos ese campo email, pero en ningun momento me tira ningun error. Me dice que todo ha sido editado correctamente. Ahi agregue el codigo de las validaciones que tengo en el modelo, no veo ninguna rara.

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando hagas el request, revises el log que te muestra donde estás ejecutando tu `rails server`, o también puedes revisar en `log/development.log`. No mencionaste si usas alguna gema de autenticación y si ves que haya algo en particular en la configuración que pueda estar bloqueando su edición, insisto en esto, porque por ejemplo en `devise` si tienes activado `:confirmable`, necesitas confirmar el correo para que efectivamente se cambie.

Comment: Muchas gracias @AlterLagos por tus sugerencias. En el log de mi rails server logre identificar una reconfirmacion que solicitaba del email para que se modifique. Muchas gracias !

Comment: Me alegro. Si encontraste tu solución, recuerda agregarla como respuesta por si alguien a futuro tiene tu mismo problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias a la ayuda del compañero @AlterLagos pude encontrar mi error. Lo que hice fue revisar el log donde tengo mi server corriendo y comprobe que me solicitaba una re confirmación del email al ejecutar la acción de editar, por lo que revise el email y me estaba llegando el correo de confirmación a spam.

Saludos cordiales,